# First order non-linear non-homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation that I would like to solve:

$$v'(t)=-\frac{k}{m_o-c\cdot t}\cdot v(t)^2+\frac{c\cdot u}{m_o-c\cdot t}-g$$

Where $k$, $m_o$, $c$, $g$ and $u$ are all constants. If I'm not mistaken, this appears to be a Riccati differential equation, due to the $v(t)^2$ term. The only initial condition I have is $v(0)=0$.

Comment: By curiosity, why is the mass decreasing ?

Comment: In short, the equation describes the velocity of a rocket. The mass lost is the propellant ejected.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{k}{m_o-c t} v(t)^2+\frac{c u}{m_o-c t}-g$$
Why don't you simplify in changing of variable ?
$$\quad x=ct-m_o$$
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=A(x)\: v(x)^2 +B(x)\quad\text{with}\quad\begin{cases} 
A(x)=\frac{k}{cx} \\\
B(x)=-\frac{u}{x}-\frac{g}{c}  
\end{cases}$$

This is a Riccati ODE. The usual change of function is $\quad v(x)=-\frac{1}{A}\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}$
$$v(x)=-\frac{c}{k}x\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}$$
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{c}{k}\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{c}{k}x\frac{y''}{y}+\frac{c}{k}x\frac{(y')^2}{y^2}=\frac{k}{cx} \left(-\frac{c}{k}x\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)} \right) ^2-\frac{u}{x}-\frac{g}{c}$$
After simplification :
$$y''(x)+\frac{y'(x)}{x}-\left(\frac{k\:u}{c}\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{k\:g}{c^2}\frac{1}{x}\right)y(x)=0$$
This is a Bessel ODE. See Eq.(6) in : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

Solve it in terms of modified Bessel functions.

Comment: Great work! One issue I encountered, however... using the formula from Bowman, the $1/x$ term in the coefficient of $y(x)$ must be positive in order to derive a real value for $β$.

Comment: No problem. This is the same formula with modified Bessel functions $I$ and $K$ instead of Bessel $J$ and $Y$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_Iα,_Kαl